# angular 6 whats for style.js in the build

Tags: angular, sass

Peeping in the html source

of my SPA build with ng 6 using sass

I found these list of files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

I'm wondering what's style.js for?

I'm importing bootstrap

in my style.scss like

(I do that because if I put
bootstrap in angular.json I can't have
my custom theme see variables)

```
@import "./assets/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 11):

With the development build global styles are extracted to .js files whereas with the production build they are extracted to .css files. To change this default behavior use `--extract-css` option or it's alias `-ec` with the `ng build` command.

### What is the reason for using js to extract css in dev builds?

Every file/module we want to be used in the bundle webpack expects to be a valid JavaScript module. And certainly styles.css is not a valid JavaScript module. So we need something to turn this CSS module into JS module. And this is where loaders come in. Here is what webpack docs say about loaders:

Loaders are transformations that are applied on the source code of a module. They allow you to pre-process files as you import or “load” them… Loaders can transform files from a different language (like TypeScript) to JavaScript, or inline images as data URLs.

More:
[**This is how angular-cli/webpack delivers your CSS styles to the client**](https://indepth.dev/this-is-how-angular-cli-webpack-delivers-your-css-styles-to-the-client/)

Comment: But why? What is the reason for using js to extract css in dev builds?

Answer (score 1):

The style.js is all your css files that are included in your style array in angular.json file.

Comment: thanks for the reply but there also a couple of style tags with all my css so I dont see the point to have css in both side

Comment: You can extract your css to external file using extract plugin in the webpack configuration.