# How to restore CSS bundling to Angular 8 project in Visual Studio after using Angular 6 template

Tags: angular, visual-studio

Following the instructions at this link:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-an-angular-8-app-with-asp-net-core/
I created a new project in Visual Studio 2019, using the Angular template, which creates a project in Angular 6. I deleted the ClientApp folder and used the Angular CLI to create a new ClientApp app/folder in it's place. Everything is working correctly, however the styles are being handled differently.

In the original project generated by the template, css files that I added to angular.json were bundled into styles.css and the file was automatically referenced in the index.html. In the new version 8 project, the content of the css files are being added in  tags into the head of index.html.

I have tried using both development and production mode, and it doesn't seem to make a difference. I have the old project backed up and have compared the angular.json and package.json files. While there are some differences, nothing stuck out to me as the cause. The VS template doesn't seem to generate a webpack.config.js, so there wasn't anything there for me to look at.

**Angular.json: (orig vs new)**

[image: Angular.json from the template v6 project]

[image: Angular.json from the newly generated v8 project]

**Package.json: (orig vs new)**

[image: Package.json from the template v6 project]

[image: Package.json from the newly generated v8 project]

**Results: (orig vs new)**

[image: Styles.css using the template v6 project]

[image: Styles using the newly generated v8 project]

There are probably many ways to accomplish this, but I'm mainly interested in what is enabling the functionality in the original project. There must be some configuration produced from the original project that the new project doesn't have.

Comment: So continuing to research this, it sounds like this is related or maybe the issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50427882/2452884

Answer (score 0):

Based off my comment above, after continuing to research, I modified this scripts key in package.json from

```
    "build": "ng build",
```

to

```
    "build": "ng build --extract-css",
```

and that works. The original package.json does not need this. I'm not sure if it's a change due to the Angular version, but at least this solves it without adding a lot of needless stuff.